# Polymorphic object without members?

Tags: c#, oop

This is a design question.

We were given an exercise in which the following classes are relevant:
Vehicle (abstract base), Car (inherits from Vehicle), Engine (contained within the abstract Vehicle), ElectricEngine/FuelEngine (inherits from Engine). I am planning to use the builder design pattern to facilitate the creation of Cars.

My question deals with the Engine.

The ElectricEngine has (float)CurrentBatteryHoursLeft, (float)MaxBatteryHours

The FuelEngine has (float)CurrentFuelLevel, (float)MaxFuelLevel

Now, because CurrentBatteryHoursLeft+CurrentFuelLevel have the same meaning, and MaxBatteryHours+MaxFuelLevel have the same meaning as well, I want to abstract them to the parent (Engine)

Am I allowed to do the following:
Unite them with a generalized name in the parent (Engine) ie: CurrentPowerLeft, MaxPower. this would promote reuse in favor of Object oriented correctness (or is it really?)

Are there any other options? because if I don't generalize anything (meaning Engine stays empty, acting as a shell only) then what's the point of it even existing? (is there any use for that case in practice?)

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about an abstract class Propulsion, then ElectricPropulsion, etc... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can, but I wouldn't do it.

For each engine type, there may be other factors specific to that engine that wouldn't be covered by those 2 properties. For example, in some cars the battery recharges when you brake.

UPDATE:

The point of `Engine` is to act as a parent to specific engine types. This way `Vehicle` can have an `Engine` property, but you can assign different types of specific engines to it.

Comment: 1. If there will be a need to recharge the battery when we break, then we could simply have the Car call m_Engine.AddPower(x) which could be a virtual method. but we don't even have to do that, because it could be left at Engine. (simple speed change...) isn't it ?

2. is creating an Engine class simply for a way for a car to hold an engine a good enough reason for creating this class? or in other words: "polymorphic object without members"?

Comment: 1. It wouldn't be correct to have the `AddPower()` method inside the `Engine` class, because it only applies to Electric engines, not all engines. 2. Yes, the purpose of the `Engine` class is to provide a common parent for all engines. For example, it could have a property `HorsePower` (applies to all engines). This way `Vehicle` doesn't care which specific `Engine` it has, it can still get the horsepower from it. It is not a good approach to pull something up into the `Engine` class just because you don't want it to be empty.

Comment: 1. if only the name is problematic, we could find a better name. the question really, is, if uniting a "shared-in-meaning" attribute (both describe how much more the engine can run until there is no more power) is a good thing? I guess what I'm looking for are the guidelines for the decision. I am running into this problem in a lot of design issues.
2. So, having an "empty" Engine isn't a bad thing? just for modeling the fact that the Vehicle has an engine is sufficient?

Comment: 1. As described in my first example, some engines might have variable power. So creating a property that returns a predefined power level might not apply to all engines. In this case it shouldn't be in the `Engine` class. The `Engine` class should ONLY have the things that are common between all engines. 2. Exactly, it's not a bad thing.

Comment: I think I got it:
in the future, we might have variable power. And although we could keep it as a property that returns an instance variable (and when the power changes, simply change the value of that instance variable) we wouldn't want to do that, as this would declare to the world that this value is predefined (and they could cache it, which would be a problem). instead, we would rather make it a method. and for the exact opposite reason, we wouldn't want to put it in base (it would mean for non-varying-engine-powers to look like they are). is that correct?

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it's a property or a method. What matters is whether it's in the parent class, or in the sub-class. If it's a common (method/property), it should be in the parent. If it's not, it should be in a specific sub-class. For example: you might have a diesel engine, and a fuel engine. Fuel engine might have a `RequiredOctaneLevel` property (87, 89, 91, etc.). It would be defined in the `FuelEngine` class, because it doesn't apply to diesel engines or electric engines.

Comment: Apologizes for the multiple questions, but I still haven't gotten to the bottom of it. I agree that RequiredOctaneLevel should only exist in the FuelEngine. But the MaximumJuice property of them could be shared (FuelEngine:50 liters, ElectricEngine:10 hours) so we could, theoretically go to the abstract Engine and ask: how much juice to you have left. with regards to the variable power: as I said, the specific engine could change the value of this shared variable when it needs to and the new power will be reflected by the value of this variable... am I missing something?

Comment: I guess it's a choice. Maximum power could be in the Engine class. Also, if this answer helped you please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you **should** do that, because an `Engine` has a responsibility regardless of how it is achieved. The `Engine` provides the power which moves the `Car`. To do that it has to consume something. The maximum amount an `Engine` can be fulled / charged with and the amount left to be consumed is independent of its type. Hence, abstracting from the energy type towards the purpose it serves is perfectly right. This is meant by `object oriented analysis`.